# Remove Registered ArgumentCompleters

Tags: powershell

I am writing a CLI application and want to enable shell completion. The package I am using to write the CLI app supports a few shells out of the box, but not Powershell. So I am writing my own for it.

There are of course a lot of iterations as I try to get this built correctly, and it "feels" like my tab auto-completion is using some older version of my script even though I try to update it.

I am doing this.

```
$script = {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
    # do stuff that returns list of completion options
}

Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName <cliapp> -ScriptBlock $script
```

Is there a way to de-register the argument completer and "start over"?

This script is being stored in `echo $profile` if it matters.

I can remove the script entirely from the profile, and it still seems to persist, even after windows being closed and re-opened.

Details of `$PSversionTable`. Should I be using some other version as well?

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.5127                                                                                                                         
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.5127                                                                                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this being added to a function?

Comment: It is just so tab completion works with custom completion words that are sourced from the CLI app itself. I performed a PC reboot and that helped reset some things but hopefully that isn't the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) has *no* complementary cmdlet for removing specific completers (or clearing all currently registered completers) - verify with `Get-Command *-ArgumentCompleter`). Presumably, the rationale is that such completers are meant to be registered once in a session and then used for the remainder of that session.

- Note that **`Register-ArgumentCompleter` never installs a completer *persistently***.
- If you want completers to be available in every session, add `Register-ArgumentCompleter` calls to your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file (which in turn implies that sessions started via the CLI's `-NoProfile` switch won't see them).

However, given that **only *one* completer can be in effect for a given name passed to `-CommandName`**:

- You can **effectively *remove* an active completer** for a given `-CommandName` by re-invoking `Register-ArgumentCompleter` with `-ScriptBlock $null`.
- You can ***redefine* an active completer** for a given `-CommandName` by re-invoking `Register-ArgumentCompleter` and passing a *new* completer script block to  `-ScriptBlock`.

---

You can verify this as follows:

- Define a dummy command (function) to register a completer for:

  ```bash
  function foo {}
  ```
- Define the *initial* completer for it:

  ```bash
  Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName foo -ScriptBlock { 'initial' }
  ```
- Type `foo`  (note the trailing space) followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> and see the argument expand to `initial`.
- *Redefine* the completer:

  ```bash
  Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName foo -ScriptBlock { 'redefined' }
  ```
- Type `foo`  followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> and see the argument now expand to `redefined`.